# Angularjs return value to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, return, return-value

```
angular.module('App').factory('API', ['someAPI', function(someAPI){
  var service = {};
  service.loadInfo= loadInfo;
  return service;
  function loadInfo(id) {
      var list = [];
      var items= [];
      someAPI.list.get({id: id}).$promise.then(function (result) {
        items= result;
        if (items.length === 0) {
            items= 'No results';
        } else {
          for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
            list.push(items[i].name);
          }
        }
        console.log('List:' + list); **//This print out 'List: a, b, c, d' in console**
      })
      console.log('List:' + list); **//This print out nothing**
      return list;
    }
  }
]);

//Controller
angular.module('App').controller('ProductCtrl', function($scope, API) {
    $scope.loadInfo = function (id) {
      $scope.list = API.loadInfo(id);
      console.log($scope.list); // This print out undefined
    }
}
```

This might be a silly question, In my service, the variable inside 'someAPI' function could be visited, but controller get an undefined. Appreciate if any body could explain me. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it `API.loadInfo(id)` and not `someAPI.loadInfo(id)`?

Comment: There was an another API used in my service, the name is someAPI.

Comment: Can you add any Fiddle/Plnkr?

Comment: Yes, but you said in your response to xpng's answer that you injected `API` into your controller. You don't get access to `someAPI` without injecting it.

Comment: Also you need to change your module definition from `angular.module('App')` to `angular.module('App', [])` Since at the moment you are reusing a module `App` not defining a new module `App`

Comment: If you truly registered your controller using `.controller('ProductCtrl', function(API){ ... })` then you don't even have access to `$scope` in your controller, let alone `someAPI`.

Comment: Thanks guys, can you please look at two consoles in my service, the first console.log printed out the right things, but the second one didn't, I guess that should be a difference between local variable with globle variable. But how can I pass it to controller finally?

Answer (score 0):

@James In your controller you need to pass $scope to your function (this is called dependency injection) which in simple words means passing an object to a function. Hope it helps!

Comment: Ah, forgot that, the injection was added, so the controller is like: angular.module('App').controller('ProductCtrl', function (API) {$scope.loadInfo = function (id) {
  $scope.list = someAPI.loadInfo(id);
  console.log($scope.list); // This print out undefined
}}

Answer (score 0):

the list gets returned immediately before the someAPI.list.get({id: id}).$promise is resolved. You need to do it in the promise way. Another problem is that your local variable is called **list** but you returned **List**.

I'd suggest that in your service, just do

```
return someAPI.list.get({id: id}).$promise.then(function (result) {
    items= result;
    if (items.length === 0) {
        items= 'No results';
    } else {
      for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        list.push(items[i].name);
      }
    }
    return list;
  })
}
```

and put move .then part to your controller.

```
$scope.loadInfo = function (id) {
  someAPI.loadInfo(id).then(function (result) {
    $scope.list = result;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, This part of code working in controller yet, but now I want move these to a service and share to other controllers, so all of the logic should keep in service.

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault, should be "list", but can you see the console.log before this return, it print out empty things.

Comment: did you mean list returned from service in my answer is empty? does the result have any values?

Comment: please see this plunker. it is simplified but the concept is the same. http://plnkr.co/edit/AUud22iS01OgQTqrhsjj?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Modified the dependencies and rewrite the factory call.

```
 //Controller
    angular.module('App').controller('ProductCtrl', function(API,$scope) {
        $scope.loadInfo = function (id) {

        API.loadInfo(id)
                 .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.list = data;
                     console.log($scope.list);

                 }).error(function (e, status, headers, config) {
                     //log error here
                 });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will update you when ajax finish its process.

```
$scope.$watch('list',function(val){
      console.log(val);
});
```